# How to get files from directory in same order as in windows explorer?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

how can I read the files from a directory in the same order as displayed in the windows explorer?

For example, the windows explorer lists:

```
file 1.txt
file 2.txt
file 3.txt
file 4.txt
file 5.txt
file 6.txt
file 7.txt
file 8.txt
file 9.txt
file 10.txt
file 11.txt
file 12.txt
```

while Directory.GetFiles() lists:

```
file 1.txt
file 10.txt
file 11.txt
file 12.txt
file 2.txt
file 3.txt
file 4.txt
file 5.txt
file 6.txt
file 7.txt
file 8.txt
file 9.txt
```

**[EDIT]**

Here you can find another solution for this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx?msg=3342284

Answer (score 0):

That special ordering was a [new feature added in WinXP](http://nevcal.com/eclectic/file_sorting.html).  Your best bet would be to re-implement the same sorting algorithm (see the link above for how to do it) on the collection once you've loaded the collection using `Directory.GetFiles()`.